# Facebook SDK generates expired token second time I login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook sdk v5 for php . i am using its login flow to get access token of user account and pages it manage. When user login to it gives mein extended access token (60 days validity) but if the user login again it genrates expired token with expiration date of 1970.

Heres the code I am using

```
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);

#######################################CONFIGURE YOUR APP HERE##########################
define("APP_ID", "abcd");
define("APP_SECRET", "abcd");//APP SECRET
//To find Facebook page id go to https://www.facebook.com/username{if username is not set this is your fb id}/info?tab=page_info          //Scroll to bottom of the page you will find you facebook page id
define("PAGE_ID", "abcd");//FACEBOOK PAGE ID ***USERNAME NOT ALLOWD***
////APP CONFIGURATION COMPLETE

require_once('libs/fbv5/src/Facebook/autoload.php');//Includes PHP SDK V 5
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => APP_ID,
  'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
//echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
//var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);
//print_r( get_class_methods($tokenMetadata));

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId(APP_ID);
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

 // echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
 //var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->get('/me/accounts', $accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $user = $response->getGraphEdge();
```

ON First login ATTEMPT
[image]

ON SECOND login ATTEMPT(user has authenticated app and now is direct redirect to callback url)

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177608/facebook-php-sdk-long-lived-access-token-expires-after-refresh-site but still no answers.